# xUnit: how to Assert other event of types then EventHandler<EventArgs>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I'm a beginner in unit testing and I've been searching the net for couple of hours now and I still can't find the answer to my simple question.

I have a class with the following event:

```
event Action<ITagData> OnTagHandled
```

Now I want to write a unit test to assert if the event has been raised but when I write something like:

```
Assert.Raises<EventArgs>(handler => m_rssiHander.OnTagHandled += handler,
    handler => m_rssiHander.OnTagHandled -= handler, () => { });
```

I get an error like:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.EventHandler to System.Action

Can someone tell me how I can assert an event of type `Action<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I decided to do it like this:

```
 bool wasEventRaised = false;
 m_rssiHandler.OnTagHandled += data => { wasEventRaised = true;};

 // Act
 m_rssiHandler.ProcessTag(m_tag);

 // Assert
 Assert.True(wasEventRaised);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `handler` is type of `EventHandler<EventArgs>`
so `m_rssiHander.OnTagHandled += handler` will not work

you will have to change:
`event Action<ITagData> OnTagHandled`

TO
`event Action<EventArgs> OnTagHandled` for it to work
or any child class of EventArgs and inherit ITagData interface

e.g.

```
class TagDataEventArgs: EventArgs, ITagData {}
```

and use it as:
`event Action<TagDataEventArgs> OnTagHandled`

AND assert:

```
Assert.Raises<TagDataEventArgs>(handler => m_rssiHander.OnTagHandled += handler,
        handler => m_rssiHander.OnTagHandled -= handler, () => { });
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but your solution will cause a lot of refactoring because the inheritance hierarchy is complex in our code and I don't want to refactor the whole code because of the unit testing framework limitation.