# C# XUnit test event with custom delegate without EventArgs

Tags: c#, events, delegates, xunit

I am currently writing tests for my .net framework 4.8 wpf application. I have a few events of the style

```
    public event CustomEventHandler ValueChanged;
    public delegate void CustomEventHandler(double newValue);
```

XUnit has a function to test Events. But is requires a standard eventhandler with custom EventArgs derived from EventArgs (Assert.Raises()).

How do I test the above event with XUnit if I cannot use EventArgs?

Comment: Create a wrapper function

Comment: Wouldn't this only make the wrapper function testable and not the event itself?

Comment: Did you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52956862/4728685)?